# Creating a DirectX10 Swapchain and Device by passing in a IDXGIAdapter

Tags: c++, direct3d

I am attempting to create a device and swapchain from a IDXGIAdapter. All my code succeeds untill a call to CreateSwapChain which returns DXGI_ERROR_INVALID_CALL.

MSDN says a return of DXGI_ERROR_INVALID_CALL can happen when DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC is null or the IDXGISwapChain** is null.

Im not really sure what it means by "IDXGISwapChain** is null" seeing as it is the output (im guessing it is when you actually type NULL.

my swapchain is defined as...

```
IDXGISwapChain* m_pSwapChain;
```

and my other code is...

```
IDXGIAdapter * pPrimaryAdapter = m_vAdapters.at(0); 

HRESULT hr = D3D10CreateDevice(pPrimaryAdapter,
                                D3D10_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,
                                NULL,
                                NULL,//D3D10_CREATE_DEVICE_SINGLETHREADED
                                D3D10_SDK_VERSION,
                                &m_pD3DDevice);


if(hr != S_OK)
{
    MessageBox(NULL, L"Error ###: Creation of Direct3D10 Device Failed", 0, 0);
    return false;
}

//m_pDXGIFactory->MakeWindowAssociation(hWnd, DXGI_MWA_NO_ALT_ENTER ); 
if(FAILED(m_pDXGIFactory->MakeWindowAssociation(hWnd, 0 )))
{
    MessageBox(0, L"Error ###: MakeWindowAssociation Failed", 0,0);
    return false;
}

IDXGIDevice * pDXGIDevice;
if(FAILED(m_pD3DDevice->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IDXGIDevice), (void **)&pDXGIDevice)))
{
    MessageBox(0, L"QueryInterface pDXGIDevice Failed", 0,0);
    return false;
}




DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC SwapChainDesc;

    SwapChainDesc.BufferCount = 1;
    SwapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Width = 800;
    SwapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Height = 600;
    SwapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
    SwapChainDesc.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Numerator = 60;
    SwapChainDesc.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Denominator = 1;
    SwapChainDesc.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
    SwapChainDesc.OutputWindow = hWnd;
    SwapChainDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    SwapChainDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    SwapChainDesc.Windowed = TRUE;



hr = m_pDXGIFactory->CreateSwapChain(pDXGIDevice, &SwapChainDesc, &m_pSwapChain);

switch(hr)
{
case DXGI_ERROR_NOT_CURRENTLY_AVAILABLE:
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"CreateSwapChainFailure: DXGI_ERROR_NOT_CURRENTLY_AVAILABLE", 0,0);
        return false;
    }break;
case DXGI_ERROR_INVALID_CALL:
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"CreateSwapChainFailure: DXGI_ERROR_INVALID_CALL", 0, 0);
        return false;
    }break;

};
```

Answer (score 1):

have you tried zeroing the memory of `SwapChainDesc` before assigning values? You didn't specify all the values of the structure, so unless it's zeroed some of the parameters might be invalid.

Try:

```
DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC SwapChainDesc;
ZeroMemory(&SwapChainDesc, sizeof(SwapChainDesc));

SwapChainDesc.BufferCount = 1;
....
```

Comment: That was it!!! Thanks a bunch! i was going all through MSDN lookin for the answer

Comment: I only know this because this has happened to me.